# IDE do not auto-completing with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I was learning TensorFlow and Machine Learning, I got an error that my IDE-VSCode didn't do auto-completing with tf.keras.(class or func).

My imports:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

This pic shows what I mean:

[image]

Comment: even `VSCode` may have bugs and some elements may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You were complaining that after
typing `tf.keras.`, you were hoping
to see more identifiers in
the autocomplete, e.g. `layers`.

Please understand that there's a difference
between holding a module reference
and having `import`ed all of its symbols.

You might be happier with a usage like

```
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
```

and then viewing the autocomplete
after typing `layers.`
or even after typing `tf.keras.layers.`

Comment: Thank for your answer, 

But if i use 
'import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers' , it will get another trouble. That is , some function or class couldn't be suggested.

Comment: You didn't mention which function or class. Perhaps you _also_ want to import `.models` ? Autocomplete within an IDE is not a substitute for consulting `help(tf.keras)` or reading the fine documentation website.